# Python MySQLdb Cursor returns empty results

Tags: python, mysql-python

Here is my code snippet...

First I've called __execute_query function to insert some rows and then to select few rows..
However, if executed a select query the function returns None or Empty rows... However manual sql query returns few rows..

```
def __execute_query(self, query, parameters = [], set_row_id = False):
    conn = MySQL.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(query, parameters)

    result = None
    query_type = query[0:query.find(" ")]
    query_type = query_type.lower()

    if query_type in ('insert', 'update', 'delete'):
        result = cursor.rowcount > 0
        if result:
            conn.commit()

            if query_type == 'insert' and set_row_id == True:
                """
                    Update the object with the newly saved row ID and mark
                    the object as not new.
                """
                self.__new_row = False
                    self.__row_id = conn.insert_id()
                    if self.__row_id == 0 or self.__row_id == "0":
                        self.__row_id = cursor.lastrowid
    else:
        result = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.close()
    return result
```

Comment: It would help if we knew how you _call_ `__execute_query` (especially the parameter values)

Comment: ~
    query = "select id,hostname from Setups where Status = ?"
    query = query.replace('?', "%s")
    parameters = ['Reserved']
    self.__execute_query(query, parameters)
~

Comment: Have you tried specifying parameters as a tuple ('reserved',) instead of a list?